# Connot select rows without double quote using ENUM variable type in MySQL

Tags: mysql, enums

How to select rows without using the double quotes("1").
I am design the `status` column in enum type.

```
status
enum('0', '1')
```

My Query:

```
 SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE activation_key='123456' AND status="1";
```

Result :

```
 Display 1 row
```

I am Try :

```
 SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE activation_key='123456' AND status=1;
```

Result :

```
Display 0 row
```

Is it possible to get the data without double or single quotes in `status` column?
I am a beginner of MYSQL, Sorry for my bad question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**An enumeration value must be a quoted string literal**. And to query a string you must enclose it in quotes.

If you make enumeration values that look like numbers, it is easy to mix up the literal values with their internal index numbers.

```
numbers ENUM('0','1','2')
```

> If you store 2, it is interpreted as an index value, and becomes '1'
>   (the value with index 2). If you store '2', it matches an enumeration
>   value, so it is stored as '2'. If you store '3', it does not match any
>   enumeration value, so it is treated as an index and becomes '2' (the
>   value with index 3).

```
mysql> INSERT INTO t (numbers) VALUES(2),('2'),('3');
mysql> SELECT * FROM t;
+---------+
| numbers |
+---------+
| 1       |
| 2       |
| 2       |
+---------+
```

More details [ENUM in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer